# Añadir filas a tabla con jquery dinamicamente

Tags: php, html, jquery

Muy buenas,

Llevo ya un buen rato intentando implementar esto pero no lo consigo.

Lo he intentado así:

```html
    <script>

 htmlTags = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="scan[]" id="sc"/></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>';
  
  

    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('input:first').focus();
  
  $('input').focusout(function(){
   $('#table_t').append(htmlTags);
        });
        
  
    });
</script>
</html>
```

*PD: de inicio la tabla tiene dos "tr" (con un "input" cada una).

Intento hacer que cada vez que se rellene el "input" y se salte de campo (pulsando TAB), se añada una fila nueva, pero solo funciona 2 veces, después no sigue añadiendo más.

Soy novato en jquery y ajax...

Un Saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El evento `focusout` debería estar ejecutándose siempre apuntando al último `input`, y para lograr esa referencia necesitamos un contexto mayor en jerarquía para tal `input` en este caso es tu `table` con el id `table_t`.

Entonces quedaría de esta manera:

```js
const htmlTags = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="scan[]"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>';
  
const $tableT = $('#table_t')

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input:first').focus();

  $tableT.on('focusout', 'input:last', function() {
    $tableT.append(htmlTags);
  });        

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_t">
  <tr><td><input type="text" name="scan[]"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias Christian, pero necesito que antes de poner el foco en la ultima fila se añada otra nueva.

Tu respuesta me ha servido de mucho, solo he cambiado esto:

```js
$tableT.on('focusin', 'input:last', function() {
  $tableT.append(htmlTags);
});
```

De nuevo, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.